# How use cleveref to get theorem-like name and list item number?

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems, cleveref, thmtools

How do I need modify this source so that:

1. The first output line of Chapter 1, currently  "See ?? 1, below", becomes instead "See Problem 2.1, below"
2. The first output line of Chapter 2, currently "Refer to ?? in these.", becomes instead "Refer to Problem 1 in these."?

Note that:

- the theorem-like environment `problems` is not itself numbered, but when referred to in a different chapter, should have the word "Problem" followed by that chapter's number, then the item number as the reference ; and
- when an item in a `problemsenum` environment is referenced within the same chapter where that environment appears, the reference should include the word "Problem".

I'm failing to understand how to use appropriate aliases or counters here.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\usepackage{aliascnt}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\crefname{enumi}{}{} 

\declaretheoremstyle[numbered=no]{probs}
\declaretheorem[name=PROBLEMS,style=probs]{problems} 

\newenvironment{problemsenum}
{\begin{enumerate}%
Solve these problems.}%
{\end{enumerate}}

\crefname{problems}{Problem}{Problem}
\Crefname{problems}{Problem}{Problem}


\begin{document}

\chapter{}\label{chap:1}

See \cref{prob:my-problems} \cref{prob-part:first-problem}, below.

\chapter{}\label{chap:2}

Refer to \cref{prob-first-problem} in these.

\begin{problems}
\label{prob:my-problems}

\begin{problemsenum}

\item \label{prob-part:first-problem}
First problem.

\item 
Second problem.

\end{problemsenum}

\end{problems}

\end{document}
```

**Partial work-around**

With the chapter labels added in the edited version above, in the preamble make definitions:

```
\newcommand{\probref}[1]{Problem~\cref{#1}}
\newcommand{\otherprobref}[1]{Problem~\thechapter.\cref{#1}}
```

And then create the cross-references in chapters 1 and 2, respectively, as follows:

```
See \otherprobref{prob-part:first-problem}

Refer to \probref{prob-part:first-problem} in these.
```

*Why the partial work-around is unsatisfactory.* Unfortunately, if I now also include in preamble...

```
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
```

... then the links in chapters 1 and 2, respectively, will be *only* on the actual problem number (here, 1) rather than on the entire phrases "Problem 1.1" and "Problem 1". And that negates, for this type of cross-reference, the option `nameinlink` I'm using for `cleveref`.

**Better partial work-around**

In his answer to [How suppress number of numbered theorem?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327992/how-suppress-number-of-numbered-theorem), Christian Hupfer provides a clever new partial solution that:

- does create cross-references with numbers to enumerate items within an unnumbered theorem-like environment (which was one of my goals); but
- does *not* fulfill one of my requirements, namely, that when the reference is in the *same* chapter where that environment occurs, then the chapter number is suppressed in the reference.

Is there some way to modify Hupfer's answer so as to fulfill my requirement #2 at the top of the current post?

Here in essence is Hupfer's clever answer, modified slightly to fit my situation, with the unit divisions being chapters rather than sections (and added colored links, extra text to show readily where the links point, etc.):

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[colorlinks, linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\declaretheoremstyle[numbered=yes,headpunct={}]{probs}
\declaretheorem[name=PROBLEMS,style=probs,numberwithin=chapter,preheadhook={\let\theproblems\relax},postheadhook={\newcommand{\theproblems}{\thechapter.\arabic{problems}}\leavevmode}]{problems} 

\newlist{probenum}{enumerate}{1}

\setlist[probenum,1]{label=({\arabic*)},ref={Problem~\thechapter\,(\arabic*)}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}

In \ref{fooother} you will prove that \dots .

\begin{problems}
\begin{probenum}
  \item foo \label{foo} \lipsum[1]
  \item bar \label{bar} \lipsum[2]
\end{probenum}
\end{problems}

In \ref{bar} and \ref{foo}, you already proved that \dots .
In \ref{fooother} you will prove that \dots .


\chapter{Second chapter}

\begin{problems}
\begin{probenum}
  \item foo \label{fooother} \lipsum[3]
  \item bar \label{barother} \lipsum[4]
\end{probenum}
\end{problems}

Earlier in \ref{bar}, you had already showed that \dots ; now in \ref{fooother} you just showed that \dots .

\end{document}
```

Comment: No counter -- no label, unless explicitly setting `\@currentlabel`

Comment: So some other approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *want* to number your `problems` environment, but hiding the number.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{aliascnt}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headformat=\NAME\NOTE,
]{probs}
\declaretheorem[
  name=PROBLEMS,
  style=probs,
]{problemsinner}
\newenvironment{problems}
  {\problemsinner Solve these problems.}
  {\endproblemsinner}

\newlist{problemsenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[problemsenum,1]{label=\arabic*}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@problemsenumi}{\maybe@thechapter{\thechapter}}
\protected\def\maybe@thechapter#1{%
  \ifnum#1=\value{chapter}%
  \else
    #1.%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\crefformat{problemsenumi}{#2Problem~#1#3}
\Crefformat{problemsenumi}{#2Problem~#1#3}
\crefformat{problemsinner}{#2#3}
\Crefformat{problemsinner}{#2#3}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}\label{chap:1}

See \cref{prob-part:first-problem} in a different chapter.

\chapter{Second}\label{chap:2}

Refer to \cref{prob-part:first-problem} in this chapter.

\begin{problems}
\label{prob:my-problems}

\begin{problemsenum}

\item \label{prob-part:first-problem}
First problem.

\item 
Second problem.

\end{problemsenum}

\end{problems}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Technical note: I used A6 paper format to produce the image.

Comment: Nice that this method does *not* require messing with `preheadhook` and `postheadhook` while retaining use of `\newlist` and `\setlist`. I had completely overlooked the possibility of using `\crefformat`.

Comment: Seems to do everything I need, and it works nicely with `hyperref`, too. Let me just bang on this method within my complicated book-length (`memoir`) before accepting the answer.

Comment: If in the example the item "Second problem" also has a label `\label{prob-part:second-problem}`, then neither `\cref{prob-part:first-problem,prob-part:second-problem}` nor `\crefrange{prob-part:first-problem}{prob-part:second-problem}`works here.

Comment: I can live with the `\crefrange` issue by substituting `\cref{...}--\creflabel{...}`. Probably likewise for the `\cref{..., ...}` issue, but always a shame to have to do things ad hoc manually that `cleveref` was designed to do automatically.

Comment: @murray You're asking for something the package is not designed for.

Comment: Which package are you referring to -- `enumitem`?

Comment: I find that with several of these `problems` environments within a single chapter, it's easy to continue the same series of numbers from one to another by initializing a global counter (`\setcounter{problemnumber}{1}`) at the start of each chapter; and then add to the `\setlist[problemsenum,1]...` command the key expressions `after=\stepcounter{problemsenumi}\setcounter{problemnumber}{\value{problemsenumi}},
    start=\value{problemnumber}`. Perhaps `enumitem`'s `start` / `resume` keys can do the same thing, but I didn't see how.

Comment: @murray I was referring to `cleveref`. I guess that you want to use `resume` and add code to `\chapter` in order to stop resuming.

Comment: `resume` does not work at all as option to `\begin{problemsenum}`; neither `series=...` nor `resume` are accepted as key options to `\setlist[problemsenum,1]`. Docs for `enumitem` just don't show how to use these with `\setlist`.

Comment: Found a snag: if, as I do need, I include formatting of the `label` in `problemsenum` ( `\setlist[problemsenum,1]{label=\bfseries\sffamily\arabic*.,.}` ).then the link produced with `\cref` and (and using`hyperref`) also has the item number formatted the same way. the link should be normal text, just with the coloring created by `hyperref` and not the bold and sans-serif that the corresponding item number gets when it appears in the list.

Comment: And the link produced by `\cref` for a `problemsenum` item is also, unfortunately, picking up the period that my `label` key value must include.

Comment: What is `p@problemsenumi`that is renewed in this method?

Comment: @murray It's the `p`refix always prepended to the representation of the counter when writing in the `.aux` file.