# How suppress number of numbered theorem?

Tags: numbering, theorems, thmtools

Is there a way, with `amsthm` and `thmtools` (possibly other packages, too) to have LaTeX keep track of the numbers of a particular kind of theorem, yet not have the numbers actually appear in the printed text?

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[numbered=yes]{probs}
\declaretheorem[name=PROBLEMS,style=probs,numberwithin=section]{problems} 

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\begin{problems}
Blah-blah
\end{problems}

\end{document}
```

The output I want should be:

[image]

Note that the answer is *not* simply to use `numbered=no` (or, without `thmtools`, a `\newtheorem*` declaration) — because I still want to reference the theorem's *number* (and not a name), e.g., for use with `\hyperref`.

[The issue is related to my question [How use cleveref to get theorem-like name and list item number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327606/how-use-cleveref-to-get-theorem-like-name-and-list-item-number.])

Comment: With other words, you want to have hyperlinks to the unnumbered theorems?

Comment: If the theorem (or problem) has no number, what would be the use of referencing to it as “problem 42”? How would the reader find it?

Comment: Each instance of the `problems` environment will have an enumerated list inside. I want to be able to cross-reference particular items in such a list not just by their item number, but also by the section number in which that `problems` environment occurs. (And such a cross-reference may, of course, appear in an earlier section, before the section that contains the target problem.)

Comment: By means of a counter, all enumerated lists of problems within several `problems` environments in a single section will be numbered consecutively throughout the section. Thus in, say, section 1,  a reference to the 5th problem item (in any of the problem environments) in section 2 might be "Problem 2 (5)".

Comment: @murray: Why do you not post such extra explanations right from the start? Your `problems` environment does not have `enumerate list` inside. I think, you are asking an X - Y - question :-(

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to simplify and isolate the issue raised in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327606/how-use-cleveref-to-get-theorem-like-name-and-list-item-number, in the hopes it might lead to a solution. Evidently I oversimplified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend such a style, but it is possible to trick `preheadhook` to let `\theproblems` do nothing and enable it later on again with `postheadhook`, such that the `label` option (or the `\label` command) will use the non-empty `\theproblems` anyway.

The enumeration reference can be changed however with an easy `enumitem` list specialized for `problems`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\declaretheoremstyle[numbered=yes]{probs}
\declaretheorem[name=PROBLEMS,style=probs,numberwithin=section,preheadhook={\let\theproblems\relax},postheadhook={\newcommand{\theproblems}{\thesection.\arabic{problems}}\leavevmode}]{problems} 

\newlist{probenum}{enumerate}{1}

\setlist[probenum,1]{label={\arabic*)},ref={Problem \thesection(\arabic*)}}


\begin{document}


\section{First section}

\begin{problems}
\begin{probenum}
  \item foo \label{foo}
  \item bar \label{bar}
\end{probenum}
\end{problems}


\section{other}

\begin{problems}
\begin{probenum}
  \item foo \label{fooother}
  \item bar \label{barother}
\end{probenum}
\end{problems}

In \ref{fooother}, \ref{bar} or in \ref{foo} it is shown that

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As my elaboration in comments above indicates, I do *not* want to directly cross-reference the entire `problems` environment, but rather individual list items within such an environment. Hence my citation of my earlier question. I'm trying in the present question to distill out some of the essence of the issue (I hope!).

Comment: @murray: Well, your comment came a little late, didn't it?

Comment: Your trick with `preheadhook`may still help in the actual, full, situation I'm facing!

Comment: @murray: See the update please

Comment: I don't think the update allows correctly referencing within the First section one of the problems' items from the other section. It does work OK within a single section, though.

Comment: @murray: Yes, I had left the `\protect` in the \setlist usage, that was an error  -- after removing, it works, as the screen shot shows -- from now on, no more requests and complaints!

Comment: See a related solution at: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327606/how-use-cleveref-to-get-theorem-like-name-and-list-item-number